# How to create chart in Lightning Component using SLDS

Tags: lightning-aura-components, charts

I am trying to draw different types of Charts e.g. Bar Chart, Pie Chart,Stacked Bar and Column Chart etc. in Lightning Component. Can anyone please suggest me how to draw using SLDS.
Link : https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/guidelines/charts/

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: apex:chart in VF page

Comment: You could use the D3.js library : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the SLDS examples are simply design examples... Salesforce has not provide a way to create charts in LWC or Aura components. You will need to use a third-party library for that.

The Salesforce Developer's Blog includes an example of using Chart.js that can be installed via an unmanaged package. The article is a bit old, but was useful for me a while back.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/03/building-lightning-components-chart-js.html

Comment: Used analytics:reportChart for my project. Thanks to all.